# How do I send data back to the server frequently - i.e. every second?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, http, websocket, server

I'm making a client-side Javascript/WebGL media playing app that will send information back to the Rails server. This will be a viewing history object containing things like what was watched, how long for, timestamp, etc.

The app itself encourages many short interactions with media, so I'm expecting a new viewing history entry every second (or even more frequently). My question is which method of sending data back to the server has better performance in this case? A Post HTTP request every second or using Websockets?

Or am I better off cacheing the data client-side and pushing it all in one go every few minutes?

Comment: Websockets will be better instead of making AJAX calls every second. You can try using [faye](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails) gem for implementing websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Websockets in this case. If you're expecting response from the server that often. It will be better to open a connection to the client and keep the connection alive and just "Play" ping-pong between the server and client instead of opening-closing connections each time if you choose Ajax requests. I wouldn't relay on the Client side to store this data. It can cause too many unpredictable circumstances. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use websocket-rails/websocket-rails gem for same:

[websocket gem](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails)